# How can I remove easly Shortcodes inside a Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I am tryng to get rid of shortcodes inside a Google Sheet column. I have many items such as [spacer type="1" height="20"][spacer] or [FinalTilesGallery id="37"] I just would like to cancel them. Is there any simple way to do it?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For in-place replacement, the quick option would be to use the **Find and Replace** dialog (`Ctrl + H`) with *Search Using Regular Expressions* turned on, which is more powerful than your standard Find and Replace.

- Find: `\[.*?\]` - Match anything within an open-bracket up to the very next close-bracket. This should work assuming you have no nested brackets, e.g. `[[no][no]]`.

  - If you do have nested brackets, you'll have to change this to `\[[^\[\]]*\]`. And continue to Replace All until all the codes are gone.
- Replace: Nothing.
- **Replace All**. If you don't want to affect other sheets that may be in your document, make sure you select the right range to work with, too.

This just erases everything within the brackets.

If you want to erase any redundant spaces left by this, simply Find and Replace again (with Regular Expressions) on  `+` (space and plus), which will match 1 or more spaces and replace with   (single space).

E.g.:

- `string [] [] string2` -> `string   string2` after the shortcode replacement.
- After replacing spaces, it will become `string string2`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your original strings are in the range A2:A. Place the following into B2 of an otherwise completely empty Column B (or the second cell of any other empty column):

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A,"\[[^\[\]]+\]",""))))`

I can't see your data, so I don't know what kind of information is between these shortcodes. If you find that this leaves you with concatenated pieces of data where there should be spaces between them, replace the above with this version:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A,"["," ["),"]","] "),"\[[^\[\]]+\]",""))))`

I can't teach regular expression language here. But I will note that, since square brackets have specific meaning within regex, your *literal* square brackets must be indicated with the escape character: the backslash.

Here is the regex expression alone:

`\[[^\[\]]+\]`

The opening `\[` and the closing `\]`, then, reference your actual opening and closing bracket sets. If we remove those, we have this left:

`[^\[\]]+`

Again, you see the escaped opening and closing square brackets, which I'll replace with the word *these*:

`[^these]+`

What remains there are opening and closing brackets *with regex meaning*, i.e., "anything in this group." And the circumflex symbol ^ as the first character within this set of square brackets means "anything except." The + symbol means "in any string length of one or more characters."

So that whole regex expression then reads: "A literal open square bracket, followed by one or more characters that are anything except square brackets, ending with a literal closing square bracket."

And we are REGEXREPLACE-ing any instance of that with `""` (i.e., nothing).